# Go/Mongo Driver: Index/Find isn't returning data

Tags: mongodb, go

I can use my query to filter/search for a specific user and I'm happy with that. However, It doesn't return the correct or full amount of data that I'm expecting, as shown below. I need the bio and other fields of data to be included. Even as I tried the answer down below I'm still returning the wrong data. It must be how I'm appending the data?

```golang
type Profile struct {
    Username string

    Verified  bool
    Protected bool

    Avatar string
    Banner string

    FollowerCount  int32
    FollowingCount int32
    TreatCount     int32
    LikeCount      int32

    Name     string
    Bio      string
    Website  string
    Location string
}
```

```golang
func SearchProfiles(filter string) ([]models.Profile, error) {
    results := []models.Profile{}

    filterr := bson.D{{Key: "username", Value: primitive.Regex{Pattern: filter, Options: ""}}}

    cur, err := userColl.Find(ctx, filterr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().
            Err(err).
            Msg("err1")
    }

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var elem models.Profile
        err := cur.Decode(&elem)
        fmt.Println(elem)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal().
                Err(err).
                Msg("err2")
        }
        results = append(results, elem)
    }

    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal().
            Err(err).
            Msg("err3")
    }

    cur.Close(context.TODO())

    return results, nil
}
```

searchProfiles returns this:

```
1:
avatar: ""
banner: ""
bio: ""
followerCount: 0
followingCount: 0
likeCount: 0
location: ""
name: ""
protected: false
treatCount: 0
username: "dev"
verified: false
```

getProfile returns this:

```
...
profile:Object
username:"dev"
verified:false
protected:false
avatar:""
banner:""
followercount:163
followingcount:15
treatcount:13
likecount:612
name:"developer"
bio:"23, ayooo"
website:""
location:"afk"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was how I was appending the data!!

```
func SearchProfiles(filter string) ([]models.Profile, error) {
    profiles := []models.Profile{}
    user := models.User{}

    filterr := bson.D{{Key: "username", Value: primitive.Regex{Pattern: filter, Options: ""}}}

    cur, err := userColl.Find(ctx, filterr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().
            Err(err).
            Msg("err1")
    }

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        err := cur.Decode(&user)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal().
                Err(err).
                Msg("err2")
        }
        profiles = append(profiles, user.Profile)
    }

    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal().
            Err(err).
            Msg("err3")
    }

    cur.Close(context.TODO())

    return profiles, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your Profile model additional description of every parameter that you need returned from db so they match exactly. So if you have your model with parameter 'Name' and in your mongo document it's 'name' than you need to map it with 'bson'. For example:

```
type Profile struct {
  ***
  Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  TreatCount int32  `json:"treatcount" bson:"treatcount"`
  ***
}
```

Read more here: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--modeling-documents-with-go-data-structures

Comment: This is not accurate. The documentation is clear on how field names are handled: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#hdr-Structs

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks!  It worked for me so I thought it will help him also.

Comment: I thought this was going to be the answer I was looking for, however I'm still getting the same output